# Installing a Failover Cluster Instance on a Cluster already in use for Instances hosting Always On

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, clustering, windows-server

I have been asked to install a SQL Server FCI on a 3 nodes cluster already hosting 4 different instances with Always On Availability Groups.

While I am building the lab on my machine, I am wondering if they are any drawback I should be aware of before doing it?

Comment: needs more details.

Comment: The fact that you're adding an FCI to a system that already has 4 different AGs on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

No, there seem to be no drawback sharing same cluster between FCI instances and instances with AlwaysOn Availability groups.

Thanks for you editions, help and support.